# How to resize video in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, video, styling

When displaying a video using the expo-av library, the video takes up the entire screen and some of its width gets cropped, as shown below:

[image]

Currently, here's how the video is displayed:

```js
function DisplayScreen({route, navigation}) {
    const video = React.useRef(null);
    const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});

    return(
        <View style={global.vidContainer}>
            <Video
                ref={video}
                style={global.video} 
                source = {require("../assets/demos/Bridges.mp4") }
                useNativeControls
                resizeMode="contain"
                isLooping
                onPlaybackStatusUpdate={setStatus}
            />
            <View>
                <Button
                title={status.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
                onPress={() =>
                    status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()
                }
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

and my styles (global.js)

```js
vidContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 400
    },

    video: {
        width: 400,
        height: 100,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'flex'
    }
```

I've also tried `width: window.width` for styling `video`, however with that the video just completely does not show up. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `flex` from `video` styles.

> flex will define how your items are going to “fill” over the available space along your main axis. Space will be divided according to each element's flex property.

See [Layout with Flexbox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) for details.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to fix the issue of the video not scaling at all, however now it appears to be cropping the video to the specified width/height, instead of actually resizing it. Is there a way I can actually resize it?